# CMC7 recognition with tesseract/opencv on iPhone

Tags: ios, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I am currently doing a project on iOS. The app I am developing is supposed to take a picture from a check (cheque?), and read the CMC7 number which is written at the bottom of the check.

Currently, I am working on it with openCV, because of the work that was previously done on the project before I arrived, but:

Is openCV better than Tesseract for that kind of job?

The difficulty here consists in the font that is used, which is this one :
http://www.dafont.com/fr/cmc7.font
As you can imagine, usual OCR can't recognize this font because of its shape. I think that the best way to do this job is to use the barcode of the font in order to recognize it, and not using the shape of the characters.

The think is that from what I know, Tesseract can recognize different kinds of fonts, and we can train it to a specific font, but what about this font that is used for the CMC7?
If I want to work on the barcode, is there a way to do it with Tesseract, or can't it only be used for font recognition?

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem. I don't think that it is possible to obtain features from cmc7 in barcode manner. Because you have different stroke height and position inside the number placeholder. I'm not familiar with Tesseract but for all type of correlators you may to choose features  that strongly defines categories with low variance between samples in category. We are thinking to use the scale invariant features like LBP , HOG or eigenvectors to eliminate data loosing after interpolation.

Comment: Actually, I managed to develop an algorithm able to read the barcode with OpenCV, so yes it is possible, but not easy.

Comment: I'll appreciate if you share the main idea.

Comment: Sorry, didn't come here for a long time. The main idea is just that I don't consider the CMC7 police as a police, but as a barcode. I mean here that I need to develop an algorithm able to differentiate the black lines from the white background. For this we need to have a clean photo, with quite a lot of details. You turn the photo to back and white, you then clean the disturbance by calculating the medium value of black pixels on each lines/columns. Once it's clean (it is the main issue here), you can quite easily separates the numbers from the others, and then read the barcode.